# Google Apps Script doesn't recognize "Host" header in HTTP POST request?

Tags: rest, http, google-apps-script, postman, arcgis

I'm trying to query ArcGIS Rest API from Google Apps script. Building the request in Postman works perfectly fine, but when I get the code into apps script, I'm having trouble that I cant seem to figure out. Here's the code:

```
function callEsri () {
  var url = "https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trailheads/FeatureServer/0/query"
  var params =
      {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trailheads/FeatureServer/0/query",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.20.1",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "[TOKEN]",
    "Host": "services3.arcgis.com",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Length": "125",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "data": {
    "f": "json",
    "where": "CITY_JUR LIKE '%Los Angeles%'",
    "outSr": "4326",
    "outFields": "TRL_NAME,ELEV_FT,CITY_JUR,PARK_NAME,FID"
  }
}
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

The Error I am getting is: **Execution failed: Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:Host (line 28, file "Code")**

Any reason why Google is not recognizing this and is there a way to fix this? Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Host is inferred from the url. No need to specify it. Side note: ``data``  is a invalid parameter. You are looking for `payload`.  Practice examples in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I am very new, I will practice more. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

As @TheMaster has already noted in the comments. You are already specifying the Host in the url.

Also you can take a look at the official documentation of [`URLFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params).

And in case you want more information in the head here you have the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) on that header and also [the RFC specifying the `Host` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4).